# top attribute not working in animate function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the code below **top** attribute in **animate** function of **JQuery** not work but **opacity** attribute works correctly, What do you think about this problem?

```js
$(function() {

  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var top = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('#lan').animate({
      top: top + 'px'
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Test</title>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="lan">My First Dangerous</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Firstly, what `opacity` attribute? Secondly, if you're trying to fix an element as the page scrolls then you don't need JS, just use CSS; `position: fixed`

Comment: The element must be absolutely (or fixed) positioned for top to do what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When The purpose here is to prove that the "animate" function works.

Because you need to set the "position" value of "element" to "absolute, relative or fixed". Eg. `position: fixed;`

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var top = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('#lan').animate({
      top: top + 'px'
    }, 100);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 2000px
}

#lan {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lan">My First Dangerous</div>
```

Comment: If you've set `position: fixed` then the JS becomes entirely redundant.

Comment: The purpose here is to prove that the "animate" function works. Friend's asking it on the mind.

Comment: Scroll up and down a couple times quickly... And wait for the element to come back. ;) You'll notice it may take long... This solution does **not** avoid multiple animations to pile up in the animation queue.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette yes but it just indicates only the function is running.

Answer (score 0):

[codepen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pYPqNK)

```js
$(function() {

  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var top = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('#lan').animate({
      top: top + 'px'
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Test</title>

<style>

body{
  height: 800px;;
  overflow:scroll;
}
#lan{
  position:relative;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="lan">My First Dangerous</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Scroll and check

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Thanks @LouysPatriceBessette for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you wish to have an element to keep its place in the viewport... But with an animation showing it tries to keep up the scrolling.

It's a funny effect.

The element has to be positionned `absolute` to follow the `scrollTop` position. With position `fixed`, the position is not related to the document, but to the viewport.

Now, it is dangerous to play with an animation on scroll... The `scroll` event fires like a machine gun. You just cannot fire an animation (which has its own delay) on every scroll event. You'll just get a huge amount of the same animation piled up in the animation queue... And that's is obviously not what is expected here.

So... with the use of a flag to know if a previous scroll event already triggered the animation, you can `return` to avoid trigged some other ones.

Then, I suggest an additionnal delay to wait for end of the scrolling by the user. That is not absolutely "safe" but I came up with a 400ms delay and it is quite nice. That is because I also reduced the animation delay to 100ms (fast!). A too long animation delay may cause problems since the user can scroll again while the animation time... And the end position will be wrong.

It's not a "perfect" solution... But it may be good enough.

```js
$(function() {

  // Variable to be used as a "flag"
  scrolling = false;
  
  // Variable to store the scrollTop position
  var top;
  
  // scroll handler
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {

    // Update the top position on every scroll event
    top = $(this).scrollTop() + 10;
    
    // Prevent the rest of execution
    // before the animation already triggered animation has finished
    if (scrolling) {
      return;
    }

    // User is scrolling
    scrolling = true;
    
    // Wait a little more before starting the animation
    // 400 ms seems like a good delay.
    setTimeout(function() {

      // Animate!
      $('#lan').animate({
        top: top + 'px'
      }, 100, function() {  // Animate quite fast is suggested here
        scrolling = false;
      });
      
    }, 400);  // setTimeout delay (can be longer...)
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 2000px
}

#lan {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lan">My First Dangerous</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should put balise `<script></script>` before end `</body>`. Not in the `head` section. I hope that works

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">    
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test</title>    
</head>    
<body>    
  <div id="lan">My First Dangerous</div>    
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: Putting `script` in the `head` is not an error in itself; especially when the OP is correctly using document.ready event handlers. Your answer does not address anything the question asks